# How to associate one input to another(change one also change another)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue 2.x via `<script>`.

I have a page contains a list of users, they are shown in a table and users can edit it:

```
name                  description1              description2
1st name input        1st description1 input    1st description2 input
2nd name input        2nd description1 input    2nd description2 input
....
```

For `description1` and `description2`, they may contain a long content, but the input only show one line(I cannot use `textarea` here).

Therefore, I need to do:

If user click `description1` input, there is a big popup dialog shown such that user can see the complete content and edit it in popup, after editing, if user click `save` button of popup, then the new content will be transferred to `description1` input which user click;

If user click `description2` input, there is a big popup dialog shown such that user can see the complete content and edit it in popup, after editing, if user click `save` button of popup, then the new content will be transferred to `description2` input which user click;

and so on.

I have a `main.jsp` which includes `student.html` and the `student.html` as follows:

```
<div id="studentDiv">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description1</th>
                <th>Description2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="s in studentList" :key="index">
                <td><input v-model="s.name" /></td>
                <td><input v-model="s.description1" /></td>
                <td><input v-model="s.description2" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="popupDialog" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl modal-dialog-  scrollable" role="document">

          <div class="modal-body">
          
              <textarea v-model="popupTextArea"></textarea>
          </div>

      </div>

    </div>
<script>
studentVM = new Vue({
    name:'student',
    el: '#studentDiv',
    data() {
        return {
            studentList:[],
            popupTextArea: ''
        }
    },
    ......
})
</script>
</div>
```

`popupDialog` div is the popup dialog(bootstrap modal).

So how can I achieve my goal in Vue? How can I sync popup dialog value and input value of list student?

Comment: What is your component structure? Does the popup and description are in the same component? Maybe add some code.

Comment: @NoyGafni i added the code, plz check, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the selected student + the property of the student you want to change, and apply the change when you click the save button:

```js
data() {
   return {
     studentList:[],
     popupTextArea: ''
     selectedStudent: null,
     selectedStudentProperty: '',
   }
},

methods: {
   selectStudent(student, property) {
      this.selectedStudent = student;
      this.selectedStudentProperty= property; 
   }
   onPopupSave() {
      this.selectedStudent[this.selectedStudentProperty] = this.popupTextArea;
      // if the line above is not working reactively try using vue.set():
      // this.$set(this.selectedStudent, this.selectedStudentProperty, this.popupTextArea) 
   }
}
```

```html
<tr v-for="s in studentList" :key="index">
   <td><input v-model="s.name" /></td>
   <td><input v-model="s.description1" @click="selectStudent(s, 'description1')"/></td>
   <td><input v-model="s.description2" @click="selectStudent(s, 'description2')"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: works great, thanks! I tried `selectedStudentDescription1: null` and `selectedStudentDescription2: null` but it requires more fields if there are `description3`, `description4` and so on.